# scrollTo Jquery WILL NOT WORK, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I've used this plug in numerous times and I'm either being very dumb or having a brain fart because I just can't get it to work. I have 3 div's that I want to scroll within another div(a container div).

here's a link of the "non functioning setup" and heres the code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sc").click(function() {
    $('#main_hold').scrollTo('#m1');
    });
    $("#ac").click(function() {
        $('#main_hold').scrollTo('#m2');
    });
    $("#cc").click(function() {
        $('#main_hold').scrollTo('#m3');
    });
});
```

and the HTML 
*note the blank spaces are there for spacing without text...

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
<div id = "navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:;" id = "sc">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" id = "ac">About</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" id = "cc">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
    </header>
<div id = "main_hold" role="main">
<div id = "m1" class = "mhold">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id = "m2" class = "mhold">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id = "m3" class = "mhold">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

    <footer>

    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If there are spaces before and after the "=" of the id attribute, you might want to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a CSS style applied to your `main_hold` div with the rule `overflow: scroll;`?  If not, you may want to scroll the window instead:

```
 $.scrollTo('#m1');
```

Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Czkan/

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it either, I've done this before and never seemed to have an issue...

Comment: @Greg Thompson - That's strange.  I added a jsfiddle where scrollTo is working. Take a look and maybe it will help.  I should have asked, are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: Yeah, I copied the OP's code and made the indicated fix.  Works for me.